# How can you kill a forked process on key press?

Tags: c, fork, pid

I am creating an MP3 player using C and the current prototype is able to play an mp3 file from a list of files all the way through, then the next, without skipping tracks. I would like to add the capability for skipping tracks. Originally I had used `fork` to play the mp3 file in the child process, then wait for the user to press a key in the parent, and kill the child process (psuedo-code below).

```
/* play file using this function */
void play(char* filename)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pid_t pid;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
            play(argv[i]);
        } else {
            getchar();
            kill(pid, SIGTERM);
        }
    }
}
```

If the user only skips and does not let the child process finish executing, this code works. When a full file is played then the user attempts to skip the next track (first played all of the way through, then second track -> third track), the second and third track play at the same time. I narrowed this down to the fact that if a skip is attempted on the second track, the parent process attempts to kill the original first process (wrapped kill in a macro which printed the killed PID, PID did not update after the first track played all of the way through). I am not sure why this happens. I am open to taking an approach other than using `fork`, since it appears that the PID management is causing the issue here.

Comment: use for example queues to send commands to the process

Comment: You have other IPC options in addition to a kill signal (pipe, socket, signals, file that you watch with inotify, shared via semaphores or shared variable and use threads instead of process for your child).  It's a little fiddly to get going but why don't you start with a pipe between parent and child?

Comment: @allanWind: My guess is that OP doesn't know how to interrupt the MP3 player they are using. If they could solve that problem, the whole IPC framework might not be necessary.

Comment: What happens if the only key you hit is the Enter key?

Comment: The `play` function probably sent data to the *playing system* in advance, so killing the process does not cancels the playing... You must have a look at your sound api to understand how to cancel the play.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not PID management. The problem -- or, at least one of the problems -- is that your child doesn't die after playing its tune.

So let's say that the parent (P) fires up a child (C1) which starts playing tune 1. P is now waiting on input, and we'll assume that the user lets the tune play. When the tune finishes, C1 continues in the loop, which advances to tune 2. Now C1, and not P, forks a child (GC) (that is, a grandchild of P), which starts to play the second tune. Meanwhile, C1 starts waiting for input.

So at this point, both P and C1 are waiting for user input and GC is playing tune 2. Now, what happens if the user types something? At this point, chaos ensues.

The input could go to either P or C1. Whichever one gets the input will wake up, kill its child, and continue in the loop. So suppose that P gets the input. It kills C1 (which was waiting for input) and forks off another child (C2), telling it to play tune 2 (which is currently also being played by GC). So now C2 and GC are both playing tune 2, but at different offsets. GC will finish first, and will then spawn its own child (GGC), telling it to play tune 3. Meanwhile, C2 is still playing tune 2 so at that point tunes 2 and 3 are being played simultaneously (by C2 and GGC), and P and GC are both waiting for input.

That's certainly not what you want. A classic solution would be for the child to die, either by returning 0 or by calling `exit(0)` as soon as `play` finishes.

But that's not the entire solution, because the parent needs to wait for either of two things: user input, or the child finishing. And that's a bit of a problem. It can wait for user input by calling `getchar` or some other input function, and it can wait for the child to finish by calling `wait` or `waitpid`, but both of those are blocking functions, and when the parent is blocked on a system call, it can't check for another condition.

There are a variety of possible solutions to this problem. Probably the best solution is to use non-blocking I/O and some kind of event loop, using `kqueue` if you're on FreeBSD/MacOS or `epoll` if you're on Linux, or some cross-platform compatibility shim if you don't want to be so low-level. So obviously, that's going to be a bit of a learning curve. (Worth doing, though.)

Here's a possibly simpler quick-and-dirty approach:

- The parent spawns two processes. One waits for user input, and then terminates; the other plays a tune and then terminates.
- Then the parent waits for some child to terminate (using `wait()`). That returns the pid of the child which terminated.
- If the child terminated, the parent spawns a new child (unless there are no more tunes to play).
- If the terminal reader terminated, the parent kills the current child and spawns a new terminal reader. It doesn't spawn a new child, because the death of the current child will be reported by the next call to `wait()`, and then the parent will execute the action for "child terminated".

This is probably not the most brilliant implementation; I just threw it together for testing:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* play file using this function */
void play(char* filename) {
  // Do something useful
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  pid_t waiter_pid = -1, player_pid = -1;
  int argno = 1;
  while (argno < argc) {
    // Spawn a waiter if necessary
    if (waiter_pid == -1) {
      if ((waiter_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        int c = getchar();
        exit(0);
      }
    }
    // Spawn a player if necessary
    if (player_pid == -1) {
      if ((player_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        play(argv[argno]);
        exit(0);
      }
    }
    // Wait for something to happen 
    int status;
    int dead_kid = wait(&status);
    if (dead_kid == waiter_pid) {
      waiter_pid = -1;
      // Kill the player
      kill(player_pid, SIGTERM);
    }
    else if (dead_kid == player_pid) {
      player_pid = -1;
      // Go to next tune
      ++argno;
    }
    else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Mysteriously caught death of %d\n", dead_kid);
    }
  }
  if (waiter_pid != -1) {
    kill(waiter_pid, SIGTERM);
  }
  // Should loop on waitpid(-1,&status, WNOHANG) until all the
  // children are reaped. Maybe I'll add that later.
}
```

Note that there is the potential of a one-byte backchannel from (dead) child to parent via the status code. So the terminal waiter could return the actual character received, letting the main loop decide what to do (eg. terminate the current tune, or terminate all tunes, or repeat the last tune, or whatever.)